# listing audio and video together in android

Tags: android, listview, audio, video, mediastore

I need to list every Audio and video files together in a listview.

I know how to list Audio and how to list video separately using

```
 MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
 MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

Is there any other way i can list both audio and video together.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code,

```
File home = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 

if (home.listFiles( new MusicFilter()).length > 0) { 
    for (File file : home.listFiles( new MusicFilter())) { 
        songs.add(file.getAbsolutePath()); 
    } 
    ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
          (this,R.layout.song_item,songs); 
    setListAdapter(songList); 
} 

class MusicFilter implements FilenameFilter  
{ 
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  
    { 
        if (name.endsWith(".mp3")||name.endsWith(".3gp")||name.endsWith(".mp4"))
             return true;
        else
             return false;
    } 
}
```

Here songs is a ArrayList which stores the actual path of the song.

Comment: What about flac, ogg, avi, etc?

Comment: @Timmmm i think without any problem you could have added them with that if condition..and yes I have doubt..is that..those format supported in android?

Comment: The trouble is it depends on the device, so I am not sure you can do it this way robustly. Better than nothing though I suppose.

Comment: @Timmmm how the code written above is dependent on device..please explain me..cause I have no that much idea..